# forking a process and waiting for child to exit

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, fork

Iam programing in C language and trying to learn the concepts of forking a process , bt iam getting 
confused with the output of the following program. So i need some explanation regarding this to proceed.

```
        int main() {
            pid_t pid;
 24         int status, died;
 25         switch(pid = fork()){
 26                 case -1: printf("Can't fork\n");
 27                          exit(-1);
 28                 
 29                 case 0 : printf(" Child is sleeping ...\n"); 
 30                          sleep(5); // this is the code the child runs
 31                          //exit(3); 
 32                          
 33                 default:
 34                          printf("Process : parent is waiting for child to exit\n");
 35                          died = wait(&status); // this is the code the parent runs 
 36                          printf("Child's process table cleared...\n");
 37         }
 38         return 0;
 39 }

The output of the above program is :

Process : parent is waiting for child to exit
Child is sleeping ...
Process : parent is waiting for child to exit
Child's process table cleared...
Child's process table cleared...
```

Here iam not getting why this "Child's process table cleared..." is coming twice. Pls explain.

Platform : Linux , gcc compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `break` in the child's `case` statement and hence the child too executes the `default` statement

You seem to have commented out `exit(3)`. It would have been better if it were there.

Answer (score 0):

i got it what i was missing ... it is because of the absence of the break statement there.If i would have used break or exit(), output wouldn't have been like this. Thanks.